# How to specify the plot region for ListPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, finite-element-method

Now I'm trying to solve a PDE and the solving domain is not regular, suppose it is a map. I used the finite element method to solve it and every nodes' value have been got, and now I want to use `ListPlot3D` to plot them,but the `ListPlot3D` doesn't work well: the plot region is over the desired region, I used `RegionFunction` to specify it, but it doesn't work.  How can I plot the proper region?

First I creat the mesh by using the function `MeshRegion`,

```
mesh = MeshRegion[trinode, Polygon@trielement];
```

The mesh is like this

[image]

and then I got every nodes' value by using the FEM and stored them in the variable `triplotpoint` in this way:

```
triplotpoint={{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2}...}
```

where the $x_n$ and $y_n$ are the coordinate of the nth node and the $z_n$ is the node's value.

Then I use the function `ListPlot3D` to plot them

```
plots = ListPlot3D[triplotpoint,PlotRange -> All,ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, {x, y}\[Element] mesh]]
```

but I didn't get the result I want.

[image]

How can the figure shows only in the mesh region?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 7):

Here's one way.  Note `NDSolve` would have returned an `ElementMeshInterpolation`, so some of these steps should be unnecessary in your use-case.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

cp = CountryData["China", "Polygon"];

mesh = DiscretizeGraphics@RegionPlot@cp; 
emesh = ToElementMesh@mesh;

cm = RegionCentroid[mesh];
values = EuclideanDistance[cm, #] & /@ emesh["Coordinates"];

ifn = ElementMeshInterpolation[{emesh}, values]

Plot3D[ifn[x, y], {x, y} ∈ emesh, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`NDSolve` example:

```
ifn2 = NDSolveValue[
  {Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0,
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == EuclideanDistance[cm, {x, y}], True]},
  u, {x, y} ∈ emesh]

Plot3D[ifn2[x, y], {x, y} ∈ ifn2["ElementMesh"], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another way:

```
triplotpoints = Partition[Flatten@Transpose[{emesh["Coordinates"], values}], 3];

normals = Transpose[{
    -Derivative[1, 0][ifn] @@@ emesh["Coordinates"],
    -Derivative[0, 1][ifn] @@@ emesh["Coordinates"],
    ConstantArray[1., Length@emesh["Coordinates"]]
    }];

Graphics3D[
 GraphicsComplex[triplotpoints,
  {EdgeForm[],
   emesh["MeshElements"] /. TriangleElement[p_] :> Polygon[p[[All, 1 ;; 3]]]},
  VertexColors -> (ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[triplotpoints[[All, 3]]]),
  VertexNormals -> normals
  ],
 Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The `normals` may be omitted for speed, if you do not care about the smooth rendering.

(Still not `ListPlot3D`. :(  Note that `ListPlot@InterpolatingFunction[..]` works nicely for a 1D `InterpolatingFunction`, but the same functionality does not seem to exist for 2D functions.)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer :)