# How to disable interpolation of ListPlot3D across points outside of the domain?

Tags: plotting, interpolation, options

**MWE**
Create and visualize the domain:

```
reg = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {Pi/3,Pi/Sqrt[3]}, {0, (4*Pi)/(3*Sqrt[3])}, {(-2*Pi)/3, (2*Pi)/(3*Sqrt[3])}, {(-2*Pi)/3, (-2*Pi)/(3*Sqrt[3])}, {0,(-4*Pi)/(3*Sqrt[3])}, {Pi/3, -(Pi/Sqrt[3])}, {0, 0}}];
DiscretizeRegion[reg]
```

[image]

Apply a function to each domain point and collect a dataset:

```
f[{x_, y_}] := Sin[x] Cos[y];
data = Table[Append[z, f[z]], {z, MeshCoordinates[DiscretizeRegion@reg]}];
```

Plot the result

```
ListPlot3D[data, ImageSize -> 500,BoxRatios -> {Automatic, Automatic, 2}, ViewPoint -> Top]
```

[image]

**Problem**

The problem is that Mathematica interpolates across the concave part of our domain and fills that space with plot for which there is no real data. I want to remove this and simply have a 3D list plot which ends at the boundaries of the domain `Region` I defined. Can this be done?

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): [How to specify the plot region for ListPlot3D?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98917/484)

Comment: I think the point `{(2*Pi)/3, (-2*Pi)/(3*Sqrt[3])}` probably shouldn't be in your polygon.  I don't believe deleting it solves your problem...

Comment: Yes, you are right, I've edited `reg` to remove it.

Answer (score 5):

Using a [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) and [`MaxPlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxPlotPoints.html),

```
dreg = DiscretizeRegion[reg];
ListPlot3D[data, ImageSize -> 500, 
 BoxRatios -> {Automatic, Automatic, 2}, ViewPoint -> Top,
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, RegionMember[dreg, {x, y}]], 
 MaxPlotPoints -> 30]
```

[image]

You can actually get a better 3D graphic in this case if you leave out the `ListPlot3D` altogether, and just add a third coordinate to each point in the mesh:

```
reg = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {Pi/3, 
     Pi/Sqrt[3]}, {0, (4*Pi)/(3*Sqrt[3])}, {(-2*Pi)/
      3, (2*Pi)/(3*Sqrt[3])}, {(-2*Pi)/
      3, (-2*Pi)/(3*Sqrt[3])}, {0, (-4*Pi)/(3*Sqrt[3])}, {Pi/
      3, -(Pi/Sqrt[3])}, {0, 0}}];
f[{x_, y_}] := Sin[x] Cos[y];
dreg = DiscretizeRegion[reg];
pts = {#1, #2, f[{#1, #2}]} & @@@ MeshCoordinates[dreg];
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[pts, MeshCells[dreg, 2]], ImageSize -> 500,
  BoxRatios -> Automatic, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The only issue I see here is that it isn't so easy to get the same surface coloring in a `GraphicsComplex` as you do for the `ListPlot3D`.  The option `VertexColors` would be the best way to do it I think......

Comment: Is there any way to get the appropriate shape with the mesh as given by `dreg`?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question.  Are you looking to take the `MeshRegion` `dreg` and reshape it, rather than using `ListPlot3D`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I still want to use `ListPlot3D` and want the final output you've given, but with the mesh drawn not as squares but rather as the mesh connections originally drawn by `dreg`. Does that make sense?

Comment: To add more information, I would want the output as given by `ListPlot3D[data, ImageSize -> 500, 
 BoxRatios -> {Automatic, Automatic, 2}, ViewPoint -> Top, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, RegionMember[dreg, {x, y}]], 
 Mesh -> All]` (added in `Mesh -> All`), but without, of course, the extraneous region. If you add in `MaxPlotPoints -> 30`, it undesirably changes the underlying mesh.

Comment: Try this:  `pts = {#1, #2, f[{#1, #2}]} & @@@ MeshCoordinates[dreg];
Graphics3D[
 GraphicsComplex[pts, MeshCells[dreg, 2]], ImageSize -> 500, 
 BoxRatios -> {Automatic, Automatic, 2}, ViewPoint -> Top]`  You may wish to toy around with `VertexColors` to get the image just right, but to me that looks far better than any of the `ListPlot3D` results.

Comment: Oh wow, that works really well! Thank you very much! (I think that this solution can be added to your original answer for the case where keeping the mesh is desired.)